# How can I encode audio with Nero AAC Encoder using Mac OS X?

Tags: audio, encoding

The *Nero AAC Encoder* encoder is far superior sound-wise to `libfaac` that comes with `ffmpeg`, but the encoder is only available for Windows. How can I encode using this encoder on Mac OS X?

Other, even better alternatives are encouraged as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`neroAacEnc`](http://ftp6.nero.com/tools/NeroAACCodec-1.5.1.zip) is also available for Linux. If you find that is works for you in OS X then you can use `ffmpeg` to pipe to this encoder and then mux with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -f wav - | neroAacEnc -ignorelength -if - -of audio.mp4
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -c copy -map 0 output.mkv
```

However, FFmpeg now also supports the external encoding library from [fdk-aac](https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac) which is probably ≥ `neroAacEnc` (I'm guessing here). That being said [some tests](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/kamedo2/20120102/1325523424) consider Apple's AAC encoder (via [`qaac`](https://sites.google.com/site/qaacpage/)) to be very good, so you have the option to encode with `qaac` and mux with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Wow, a quick read on your fdk-aac link tells me it would be a good option. Really worth trying. How can I get the Linux version to work within OS X?

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund I am not too familiar with OS X, but you can always try compiling it. See this [FFmpeg OS X Compile Guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide).

Answer (score 1):

On the mac you'd be bettor off using `afconvert`.  Command line tool to quicktime aac encoding.

```
afconvert -f m4af -d aac -q 127 -s 3 <input file>
```

There's also a user quality setting `-u vbrq <1 to 127>`  I tend to use 105 for around 250kbps and that example above is using true vbr.

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on using Nero's encoder on a mac, you can always use [Mac's Bootcamp](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1461) to run a virtual version of Windows and do the encoding that way. This probably isn't what you want but was just going to give you the option.

There are also a few programs that don't require Bootcamp that will open PC programs. Here are a couple. I think some have a free trial too or are free (but in beta) so you wont have to buy anything right away if you wan't to go this route:

1. [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/)
2. [Wine Bottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/)
3. [Vmware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/features.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input on this one. I was hoping not to use Bootcamp etc. but indeed the option is there.

Comment: And on the iTunes question, iTunes will not convert using the NeroAACEnc encoder.